# How to error trap for other letters when I only want Y and N?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

How do i error trap for other letters in a play again menu with python. i would like to ask the user if they "want to play again? Y/N" using try and except.

```
def playAgain():
answer = input("Play again? Y/N: ")
while answer == Y: 
    main () 
while answer == N: 
    break
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be in try-except form? A regular `if-else` would be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop to keep asking the user for a valid input until the user does so. Make the `playAgain()` function return a Boolean value instead so that the actual control logic can be made in the main program instead:

```
def playAgain():
    while True:
        answer = input("Play again? Y/N: ").lower()
        if answer in 'yn':
            break
    return answer == 'y'

def main():
    while True:
        # main code
        if not playAgain():
            break
```